# "SHOW ERRORS" does not work inside stored procedure ( Percona Server 5.6.26-74.0 )

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, percona

I use Percona Server 5.6.26-74.0 and i have a stored procedure that has a 
SHOW ERRORS statement in it. It does not seem to work inside a stored procedure but works when called outside in ad-hoc manner. I recently upgraded to this particular version of Percona Server. It worked fine in my previous version. Does anyone know why this is not working and are there any work arounds to get same working behavior of SHOW ERRORS in a stored proc?

The main stored proc where the SIGNAL is done is like this. The signal is sent to the caller of stored proc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `X`( IN in_a CHAR(64), IN in_b TINYINT  )
BEGIN
    DECLARE c_invalidState CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '40031';
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR c_invalidState
BEGIN 
  RESIGNAL;
END;

IF in_b = 0
THEN 
    SIGNAL c_invalidState
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid state Error.';
END IF;

END
```

Now I have another stored proc ( consider it as an UT sp ) that looks for the specific MESSAGE_TEXT set in the main stored proc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ut_x()
BEGIN
    DECLARE c_invalidStateUT CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '40031';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR c_invalidStateUT select "Ignoring expected 40031 exception";

    CALL X('2322',0);
    SHOW ERRORS;

END
```

SHOW ERRORS called here always returning empty set.It used to work before the percona update.

Comment: Please explain what "is not working" means.  What actually happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: Updated the question will sample code.

Comment: *"it worked fine in my previous version"* ...What version was that?  Oracle did, at some point, make some changes that were a departure from sensible behavior of the diagnostics area (fixing one thing, broke another, as I recall), so this might be an upstream issue.  Provide your previous version and maybe we can pinpoint what/when/who/why.

Comment: I'm completely not sure about the percona server i used before. It was some version from late 2012. Anyways, @Drew's answer below kind of worked for me. I shifted the SHOW ERRORS statement to CONTINUE HANDLER's body and I can see the errors now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the MySQL Manual Page for [`SHOW ERRORS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-errors.html), a diagnostic call.

In the below I create an exit handler. The main part of the Stored Procedure will error out to it. Note the `OUT` parameter, and the `IN` parameter for the command.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS force_An_Error;
DELIMITER $$
create procedure force_An_Error
(   OUT errorOccurred int,
    IN todo int -- this is the command. 1 means Force An Error
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            SET errorOccurred=1;
            SHOW ERRORS;
        END; 

    -- The real part of my stored proc is here. Error Handler is above 
    IF todo=1 THEN
        select 555xxNonsense; -- force an error !
    END IF;
    SET errorOccurred=0; -- All is fine
    select 7 as seven; -- This is fine (By the way I never get here)
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test:

```
set @testvar:=0;

call force_An_Error(@test,1);
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                        |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Error | 1054 | Unknown column '555xxNonsense' in 'field list' |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------+

call force_An_Error(@test,0);
+-------+
| seven |
+-------+
|     7 |
+-------+
```

MySQL Community Server 5.6.24